# Set property of caller of object?

Tags: objective-c

Im calling an object using a timer like so :

```
NSTimer *mainTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                                      target:thisTimer
                                                    selector:@selector(increaseSeconds)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:YES];
```

What id like to do, is have the function `increaseSeconds` set a property of the object that called it. Something like this:

```
  - (void)increaseSeconds {
       parent.label.text = whatever....;    
    }
```

Comment: If the function needs a parameter, then pass a parameter.  Spelunking through the stack  is a Very Bad Idea.

Comment: @NSResponder I never said it needs a parameter..

Comment: If you want to know what the sender is, then yes, you need a parameter.  Pass the sender to the method in question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if the easiest way would be to have an 'initWithParent:' method for when you create your 'thisTimer' object.

Comment: It would be a method that you created in order to init the object that contains the increaseSeconds method.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion here is, even if you could do this (which you can't really effectively), the "object that called it" is either `NSTimer` or `NSRunLoop`, which is probably not what you meant. There's no way to connect that back to one of the objects you're probably thinking about. If you look at your timer, you're not registering the caller with it in any way.

There are techniques you could use here with `NSTimer`. The most obvious is to store the caller in the `userInfo` dictionary. That's what it's for. But I'm suspecting that you should reconsider your design. It is very unusual to create an `NSTimer` whose `target` is not `self`, and it suggests that you have your responsibilities incorrectly assigned. Make sure that you have a good grasp of [MVC](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html) when designing for Cocoa.